# Menu icon appears in design mode but not in debug mode

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, icons

Menu icon appears in design mode but not in debug mode:

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="_Application">
        <MenuItem Header="_MasterData" Click="btnMasterData_Click">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="database.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Are you sure the image file lies in the same folder as your exe (have you set to copy the file)?

Comment: Also, what's the BuildAction for that image?

Comment: The image lies in the project root. Build action for image?

Comment: Right click on the image in VS and select properties. There you can find the BuildAction

Comment: If you do end up finding that, the BuildAction should be set to "Resource".  And with that, the icon will be embedded in the exe, so you don't have to worry about copying the actual icon file to the same folder.